# In index, why check if item already has an index? (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

**Short version**

When reimplementing `index` for a tree model, why would we first check to see if the relevant item already has an index (with `hasIndex`), returning the root index if it does not? Isn't the whole point to create an index for that item?

**Detailed version**

Consider the reimplemention of `index` in PySide's [simpletreemodel](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/060dca8e4b82f301dfb33a7182767eaf8ad3d024:examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel/simpletreemodel.py) example (full code is below). My understanding is that the `index` method is meant to take in the row, column, and parent index of a particular item, and return an index for that item using `createIndex`. But the `index` method opens with the following lines:

```
    if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()
```

I am a bit confused here. If the item does not *already have* a valid index, why return the root index? How does this method ever create an index in the first place? When I cut out the above lines, I see no deleterious effects in the application.

Since I am trying to simplify the PySide example as much as possible, I want to just remove those two lines. Will this have bad unforeseen consequences?

**Relevant code**

```
def index(self, row, column, parent):
    if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    if not parent.isValid():
        parentItem = self.rootItem
    else:
        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()
    childItem = parentItem.child(row)
    if childItem:
        return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
    else:
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hasIndex` function just performs bounds-checking. If the `row` or `column` arguments are less than zero, or outside of the range of the row or column count of the `parent` index, it will return `False`; otherwise, it will return `True`.

Also, in the example implementation, the `index` method does not return the root-index when `hasIndex` returns false: it returns an *invalid* index (the no-argument constructor of [QModelIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndex) always creates an invalid index). The model should always return an invalid index when there is no corresponding item available in the data that is being modelled.

Comment: Great thanks -- I was confused b/c the docs said about `hasIndex`: "Returns true if the model returns a valid `QModelIndex` for `row` and `column` with `parent` , otherwise returns false." This made it seem equivalent to `isValid`. How did you find this out, from the Qt source code (qabstractitemmodel.cpp)?

Comment: I thought root index *was* the invalid index (i.e., `QtCore.QModelIndex()`). I have seen this by a few authors.For instance, Summerfield (Rapid Gui Programming) writes, "In tree models, every item is either the child of another item (and therefore has a parent) *or a top-level (root) item, in which case it has no parent, which is signified by an invalid model index.* Therefore, when we call `columnCount()` with a `QModelIndex()` (i.e., with an invalid model index), we get the column count of top-level items" (p 495, emphasis added).

Comment: @neuronet. The Qt docs aren't particularly clear, but it really only makes sense for `hasIndex` to do some sort of bounds-checking. It's always worth reading the source code to check whether your assumptions are correct, though :) As for the root-index: it has to be invalid, because, as with  all invalid indexes, it doesn't represent any item in the data.